# Multiple Description Attribute in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

DescriptionAttribute not allow to be set multiple times.

Is there any way to have such opportunity to set kind of DescriptionAttribute many times to property or enum for example.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to your own question rather than part of the question text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
public class ExtraDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    private string extraInfo; public string ExtraInfo { get { return extraInfo; } set { extraInfo = value; } }
    public ExtraDescriptionAttribute(string description)
    {
        this.DescriptionValue = description;
        this.extraInfo = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling the base class constructor and remove the `Description` property. This also shows how to set the `ExtraInfo` property.

```
public class ExtraDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    public String ExtraInfo { get; private set; }

    public ExtraDescriptionAttribute (String description, String extraInfo) : base(description)
    {
        ExtraInfo = extraInfo;
    }
}
```

The description attribute will now look like:

`[ExtraDescriptionAttribute("Description", "ExtraInfo")]`